# Does $\sum\frac{\cos(n+1)\pi}{(2n)!}$ converge or diverge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So I tried putting $\cos(n+1)$ in Maclaurin form:

$$\sum(-1)^n\frac{(n+1)^{2n}}{2(2n)!}$$

and tried to use the alternating series test but can't seem to prove $a_k<a_{k+1}$

Comment: Also I'm confused if it's cos((n+1)pi) or pi*cos(n+1)

Comment: There is no $\cos (n+1)$ in the question. Under usual notation, $\cos(n+1)\pi$ means $\cos\left((n+1)\pi\right).$

Comment: The sum has the value $$-\cos(-1)$$

Comment: Note that $\cos\left((n+1)\pi\right)=(-1)^{n+1}$

Comment: It's not clear what you Maclaurin form is. It isn't the Maclaurin series of $\cos(n+1).$  The Maclaurin series has denominator $(2n)!,$ with out the additional multiple of $2.$ But that is beside the point, since you only need $|\cos x|\leq 1$ for any (real) $x,$ and when $x=(n+1)\pi,$ $\cos((n+1)\pi)=(-1)^{n+1}.$

Comment: It appears that you're using $n$ as both the input variable to cosine and as the summation index variable.

Answer (score 6):

$$\left|\frac{\cos{((n+1)\pi})}{(2n)!}\right|\leq \frac{1}{(2n)!}$$

So the series converges absolutely.

Comment: So in this case cos(n+1)pi is cos((n+1)pi) right?? The brackets confuse me. Sorry.

Comment: Yes, the notation usually means that $\cos((n+1)\pi).$ @logan

Comment: I'm embarrassed to admit I spent way too long on this question. Thanks so much!

Comment: you are welcome.

Comment: The above inequality is actually equality when $n$ is an integer. Then, $\cos((n+1)\pi)=(-1)^{n+1}.$

Answer (score 0):

Don't know where the extra $2$ in the denominator came from.

$\sum\dfrac {\cos(k+1)\pi}{2k!}=\sum(-1)^{k+1}\dfrac1{2k!}$.

You can use the alternating series test (Leibniz test) if you want:  clearly $a_{k+1}=1/(2(k+1)!)\lt1/(2k!)=a_k$.